# How to get uniqe id of div in same div

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

I have a trouble about jquery. To specific say, I have a one div as and in this div I create a lot of div using append() function. Each div of these has onclick function.  I need to get id of div when ı clicked which I want. jquery,

```
for (var i=1; i<=count ; i++){
$('#pages').append('<div onclick="GoToImage(); return false;" id='+i+'; class="pageNo"> </div>'); 

}
```

Then GoToImage function here,

```
function GoToImage(){
var divs = $( "div" ).get();


divs = jQuery.unique( divs );
showSlide(divs);}
```

I tried many ways that does not work. Which function do I have to get id of clicked div.

Answer (score 1):

Don't use inline event handlers - they're obsolete and will cause you lots of problems.

In this case, you can use event delegation:

```
$('#pages').on('click', 'div.pageNo', GoToImage);
```

Do this just once, outside of the loop.  Remove the `onclick` attribute from your code.   Any clicks on the divs will bubble up to the `#pages` element where they will be handled by `GoToImage`.

With `GoToImage` you can use `this` to reference the clicked div, and `this.id` to get that element's ID, should you actually need it:

```
function GoToImage(ev) {
    var id = this.id;
    ...
}
```

Comment: I serch sth that your solution lead the way. but I do not understand and I could not do that. Why do I need to use on() ? Can you give me any example link ?

Comment: You use `.on()` because that's how jQuery works - it's fundamental and _very basic_ jQuery usage - see http://api.jquery.com/on/

Comment: So because of on() ı do not have to use id number of elements specifically. Anyway it return the clicked element ? Am I right ?

Comment: @user2908225 whether you need the `id` or not depends on your implementation of `GoToImage`.  Your current version doesn't appear to use it.  But yes, within the function `this` will be the clicked element.

Answer (score 0):

Inside `GoToImage` do a

```
var id = this.id;
```

which will give you the id of clicked div

Comment: `$(this).attr('id')` is a jQuery anti-pattern - use `this.id`.

Comment: also note that inline event handlers don't even set `this` properly - it has to be passed like so: `onclick="GoToImage(this)"`.  It's best to avoid them altogether.

Answer (score 0):

Simply pass `this` to `onclick()` method: which will pass whole `div` object to a function and you can get it's attributes

```
$('#pages').append('<div onclick="GoToImage(this); return false;" id='+i+'; class="pageNo"> </div>');
```

And in function you may get ID

**Updated**

```
function GoToImage(MyDivelement){
   var id = MyDivelement.id // here you can get IDs you want on clicking div
}
```

Comment: Thnks friend. I get sth. But I do not understan how it works this code. What do this element in the code ?

Comment: @user2908225 element is the div object which is passed via `GoToImage()` when you click on div.

Comment: @user2908225 You can accept appropriate answer if it helped you. :)